# Asp,net Core Controller Action body timeout

Tags: asp.net, shopify-app

So I am receiving a Shopify webhook request to my asp.net application. I keep getting the following error.

```
'((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest)this.Request).Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

If I put Request.Body it says item timed out. I am not sure how to read the stream that is getting sent to my action.

I can post any extra details you request I am not sure what to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This we because I needed to read the incoming stream.